# Can't get all group items

Tags: c#, regex

I have this code:

```
string dupa = @"<div>dupa puda</div><div>udpa apad dpau</div><div>dupa</div>";
Regex test = new Regex(@"<div>(\s*?(\b[dupa]*\b))*?\s*</div>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var allDefs = test.Matches(dupa);
```

When I look inside Matches array (allDefs), groups looks like this:

```
{  
  <div>dupa puda</div>, -> matching all
   puda, -> matching (\s*?(\b[dupa]*\b)) group
  puda -> matching (\b[dupa]*\b)
}
```

So, I loose `dupa`. What I need is to find all words matching `(\b[dupa]*\b)`, but I can get just last one that matchs patter. Is there any way to get values  `{ dupa, puda }` for first match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does capture all the repetitions of the inner group, but you'll have to inspect the [`Captures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection to get all of them. For example:

```
foreach (Match m in allDefs)
{
    foreach (Capture c in m.Groups[2].Captures)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("----");
}
```

produces the output

```
dupa
puda
----
udpa
apad
dpau
----
dupa
----
```

Or if you want to use a little Linq:

```
var words = 
    from Match m in allDefs
    from Capture c in m.Groups[2].Captures
    select c.Value;
// { dupa , puda , udpa , apad , dpau , dupa }
```